# TypeMock Faking static method in static class

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, typemock-isolator

Using TypeMock Isolator...

I am trying to Mock a static method call that is inside a static class but it keeps calling the original code.

I ran across [this](http://www.typemock.com/answers/10458/faking-static-method-on-static-class) thread and I am doing exactly what they suggest but still not luck.

I have tried doing it 2 different ways:

1:

```
Isolate.Fake.StaticMethods(typeof(QueueDAO), Members.ReturnRecursiveFakes);
```

2:

```
Isolate.WhenCalled(() => QueueDAO.UpdateQueueStatus(queueCmtId, CmtQueueStatus.Error)).IgnoreCall();
```

Neither solution works.   Does it have something to do with the enumeration that is passed in?

Comment: From reading that thread, it looks like you actually have to use both 1 and 2 in conjunction instead of separately.  Have you given that a try?

Comment: I thought it actually said the opposite.  That you did not have to use both calls (that it was a redundant call).  Regardless, I gave that try and it still gave me the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Both should work. By default arguments are ignored so the second should work too. 
Do you have [Isolated] on the test class or method?

You might have another isolate method that overrides this one. 
Please see if a simple test that isolates updatequeuestatus and then calls it directly works?
If not turn on logging and send them to support (at) typemock.com for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

The object passed in as the typeof should be the class which contains the static methods, not the object itself.

Isolate.Fake.StaticMethods(typeof(QueueDAO));

Does the QueueDAO object contain static methods, or is there an extensions class?